# Liquid map error "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered"

Tags: json, mapping, special-characters, liquid, dotliquid

I have a very simple Liquid map (extract here below):

```
{   
    {% if content.DisplayLastName__c %}
    "DisplayLastName__c": "{{ content.DisplayLastName__c }}",
    {% endif %}
}
```

The input message of the map is the following:

```
{
        "DisplayLastName__c": "é\" r",
        "FirstName": "é\""
}
```

I got this error due to the fact that there is a *\"* in one field: "After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered".

Am I missing something?

Comment: In which environment/stack did you encounter this error ?

Comment: In Microsoft Azure Logic Apps.

Comment: This works with ruby liquid, this may be a [dotliquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) problem.

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue in dotnet liquid?

Comment: @MintyOwl: unfortunately, I was not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, however I don't fully know why:

```
{% assign vDescription = system.Data.Description | Replace: '\"', '\"' %}
```